# occurrences of duplicated values and returning unique values separated by comma in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following dataframe in R

```
 Number      ship_no
  4432          1
  4432          2
  4564          1
  4389          5
  6578          6
  4389          3
  4355          10
  4355          10
```

I want to find which duplicated `Number` are repeated in unique `ship_no`

```
 Number       ship_no
  4432          1,2
  4389          5,3
  4355          10
```

How can I do this in r ?

I attempted following code in R

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(Number) %>%
filter(duplicated(Number)) %>%
summarize(Number = paste0(unique(ship_no), collapse = ','))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Number) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  summarize(ship_no = paste0(unique(ship_no), collapse = ','))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we look for `Number` that is only duplicated only in one `ship_no` and then I want to filter those `Number`

Comment: @Neil You can change ` > 1` by ` == 2`

Comment: I want only those `Number` which are repeated only in one `ship_no` e.g. `4355 duplicated in only ship_no 5` and so on

Comment: I don't understand. Is this a new question? Is my answer not what you wanted? PS: there is no `4355`.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly working. I am just asking new question. I have edited the question. I want e.g `4355 duplicated in only one ship_no i.e 10`

Comment: You can't just change or ask another question like that. Just validate this one and ask another one in another thread.

Comment: how can I count `comma separated ship_no` in your code ?

Comment: Add `N = length(unique(ship_no))` in the `summarize` BEFORE `ship_no = ...`

Answer (score 1):

**Why your solution does not work:**

With the statement

```
filter(duplicated(Number))
```

You are keeping only rows that are duplicates of an earlier encountered row:

```
duplicated(df$Number)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

**Solution 1 with data.table**

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,if(.N>1).(ship_no=list(ship_no)),Number]
```

---

**Solution 2 with dplyr**

You can combine your duplicated statement with another duplicated call with `fromLast=False` as follows:

```
df = read.table(text="Number      ship_no
4432          1
4432          2
4564          1
4389          5
6578          6
4389          3",header=T)

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Number) %>%
  filter(duplicated(Number) | duplicated(Number,fromLast=TRUE)) %>%
  summarize(ship_no = paste0(unique(ship_no), collapse = ','))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can do this in three lines with `aggrgate` and `lapply`. It will result in a data.frame, where your second argument is a list containing the vectors of duplicated values.

```
# collect ship_nos for each Number into single column
mydf <- aggregate(ship_no ~ Number, data=dat, c)
# drop rows without multiple ship_nos
mydf <- mydf[lengths(mydf[["ship_no"]]) > 1,]
# sort values in ship_no columns and drop any duplicates within each list item
mydf[["ship_no"]] <- lapply(mydf[["ship_no"]],
                            function(x) sort(x[!duplicated(x)]))
```

This returns

```
mydf
  Number ship_no
1   4355      10
2   4389    3, 5
3   4432    1, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df1)[df1[,  .I[.N > 1], Number]$V1])[, .(ship_no = toString(ship_no)) , Number]
#    Number ship_no
#1:   4432    1, 2
#2:   4389    5, 3
#3:   4355      10
```