# finding duplicates in only one group in R

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
Number      ship_no
4432          1
4432          2
4564          1
4389          5
6578          6
4389          3
4355          10
4355          10
4689          12
4689          12
```

I want to find duplicated `Number` only in one `ship_no`

```
Number       ship_no
 4355          10
 4689          12
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could simply do:

```
df[duplicated(df),]

   Number ship_no
8    4355      10
10   4689      12
```

since

```
> duplicated(df)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Maybe wrap it in unique() if there are more than two duplicates possible of the same row.

---

To keep the other duplicates:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Number) %>%
  filter(duplicated(Number) | duplicated(Number,fromLast=TRUE)) %>%
  summarize(ship_no = paste0(unique(ship_no), collapse = ','))

  A tibble: 4 x 2
  Number ship_no
   <int>   <chr>
1   4355      10
2   4389     5,3
3   4432     1,2
4   4689      12
```

Comment: Its removing all the duplicates

Comment: That is what your question asks for? To keep the others to, you could use [my code from your previous question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264202/occurrences-of-duplicated-values-and-returning-unique-values-separated-by-comma)

Comment: How can I count `comma separated ship_no` in above code?

Comment: Are you looking for the number of duplicates? This feels like another question again? `df %>% group_by(Number)  %>%
  summarize(n = n_distinct(ship_no))` returns the number of unique values per group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  unique(.SD[.N > 1 & uniqueN(Number)==1]) ,  ship_no]
#   ship_no Number
#1:      10   4355
#2:      12   4689
```